# How can I stub default method with BDDMockito?

Tags: mockito, bdd

I have an interface with defaults method.

```java
interface MyInterface {

    default ByteBuffer put(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And I used to stub the method with the following code.

```java
        doAnswer(i -> {
            return buffer;
        }).when(spy).put(any());
```

Now I'm trying to use `BDDMockito`.

```
            given(spy.put(any()))
                    .willAnswer(i -> {
                        ByteBuffer buffer = i.getArgument(0);
                        assert buffer != null;
                        print(buffer);
                        assert buffer.capacity() == BYTES;
                        assert buffer.limit() == buffer.capacity();
                        assert buffer.remaining() == BYTES;
                        buffer.position(buffer.limit());
                        return buffer;
                    });
```

It seems that it calls the real method.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using BDDMockito ? Mockito is not enough ?

Comment: @Dimitri Indeed. Mockito is enough. Yet I just want to try to use BDDMockito.